# How to implement 301 redirects correctly for Google Search Console site move tool?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, google-search-console

My website got a new domain yesterday.
Old: plejadium.de (SSL)
New: lucyda.de (SSL)

To redirect all URLs from old to new I wrote this into my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^plejadium\.de$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.plejadium\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.lucyda.de/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Testing some search engine result URLs and they redirect properly to the new domain.
Now I'd like to use the site moving tool on Google Search Console to make Google aware of the new domain.

But GSC says the starting page as well as some random URLs from my website don't have a 301 redirect, like for example:

```
https://www.plejadium.de/ 
https://www.plejadium.de/virtual-life/karten-gis/google-maps-mit-gpx-und-kml/
```

So I can't perform the site URL movement on Search Console and am afraid to lose all rankings.

In another Stackoverflow topic I read that there must be 301 redirects for every combination like with www and without and with https and without. www is covered in the .htaccess but I don't have any clue how to get that https thing done, because that's it what Google Search Console struggles with obvisiously.

As you might assume I'm not experienced with .htacces and got the Rewrite thing from a help blog.

Can someone help?

Comment: _"because that's it what Google Search Console struggles with obvisiously"_ - why? You said the URLs it mentioned where HTTPS URLs already? Plus, your rewriting setup doesn't even care whether the _old_ URL was requested using HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The example URLs google checks in Search Console are https URLs, I put 2 examples in my post :) And Google says they don't have a 301 redirect. So my thought was that maybe https would be the problem.

Comment: That must be an error of the tool then. There is no way any client could work its way around these redirects for any URLs from the old domain.

Comment: Okay, maybe it needs some days to recognize it correctly, I don't know.. Any cache thing or something. I had it check yesterday and today too, but will try again. Thanks :)

Comment: Visually inspecting your code and it should work. It does not check https status so will redirect http and https. I checked your two examples and they redirected correctly. Maybe try again a bit later. Does the domain use a CDN, that may delay picking up of redirects.

Comment: Thank you very much for checking, Tony!! No, there is no CDN. And yeah, today Google Search Console recognizes everything correctly , I was able to start the move process. Man, I was so confused and just had to wait a bit. Thank you guys!